# Python 3.5 print syntax error in Spyder - works in console?

Tags: python, printing, syntax, format

I'm trying to use print with .format() to create a table, but I'm getting a syntax error on:

```
print("|{:<40}|{:<40}|{:<40}|{:<40}|".format(*tableheads))
```

with tableheads being a predefined list of 4 arguments. The error I'm getting when I try to run is:

```
    print("|{:<40}|{:<40}|{:<40}|{:<40}|".format(*tableheads))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For a while I thought I'd done something wrong, but I've looked through the documentation, and even tried it in the console where it worked perfectly. For some reason though, I'm getting a syntax error when I try to include it as  part  of a function.

I'm not sure what to do, and I feel like I must be missing something, but what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a situation like this, you should immediately suspect the previous line. Can you give us more lines of context. I would look for a missing close paren or closing bracket.

Comment: Look at the line(s) above the print. Make sure you closed all parenthesis properly.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thank you both